# Gatling - Large requestbody and using different .json files for input each session

Tags: gatling

I have a 2.000 line json request body. I want to use different static json files for each virtual user. I have created 10 different files of 2.000 lines each.
How can I "feed" these 10 different files per user as in:

```
.exec(http("sendMedication")
  .post("/Patient/$sendMedication")
  .body(ElFileBody("magnus/SendMedication_request_2021.json"))
  .check(status.is(200)))
```

where "SendMedication_request_2021.json" must be i.e. random or circular per user

Could I do something like:

SendMedication_request_2021(#1).json

given I have:

SendMedication_request_2021_1.json
SendMedication_request_2021_2.json
SendMedication_request_2021_3.json

and so forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create csv file with list of your file names and pass via Gatling EL

**fileNames.csv** :

```
fileName
SendMedication_request_2021_1.json
SendMedication_request_2021_2.json
....
```

And scenario:

```
.feed(csv("fileNames.csv").random)
.exec(http("sendMedication")
      .post("/Patient/$sendMedication")
      .body(ElFileBody("${fileName}"))
      .check(status.is(200)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to "create" the filenames based on my preceeding request (the filenames in filenames.csv)? As in 
.exec(http("getMedication").post("/Patient/$getMedication")
      .check(bodyString.saveAs("SendMedication_request_2021_???.json")))

Comment: Yes, but you need save via findAll and then use gatling EL
```"${fileName.random()}" ```

p.s. you need to figure out how to turn the response body into an Seq